# What will be the vector equation of line in this case?

Tags: vectors, 3d, parametric

Given two points, we can definitely find out vector equation of line, but what if I have only a single point and a slope (which is a result of a partial derivative). How do you convert that into a complete vector equation?

Comment: Is this in two dimensions or three? You have the 3d tag but slope doesn't make sense in three dimensions. You need either two points or a point and a vector. If the partial derivative is with respect to $x$ then your vector would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\hat i$.

Comment: @John Douma So, I have a point here and a slope in $x$ direction so it should be line $point vector + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat i = \overrightarrow r$ And yes it's in 3d. Would that be correct to say.

Comment: Yes, but please don't call it a slope. In 3d, unit vectors define directions so you have a point and a rate of change in the $\hat i$ direction. It is okay to call it the $x$ direction.

Comment: @John Douma yeah thanks I'll keep that in mind while referring to partial derivatives.

Comment: One more thing: in your equation for the line you also need a parameter, usually called $t$ that takes on all real numbers. Your final equation will be $(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0) + t(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},0,0)$ where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is your point.

Comment: Yeah thanks I forgot to add $t$ there.

Answer (score 1):

How about $p+t\cdot (1,m)$, where $p$ is the point and $m$ the slope...

Comment: Why $(1,m)$ here?

Comment: @Manny46 Has slope m...

Comment: we could have chosen $(0,m)$ too then

Comment: @Manny46 no, $(0,m)$ is vertical.

Comment: now I see it thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\vec r$ = $\vec a$ + n($\vec b$)

where $\vec r$ is the equation of the line, $\vec a$ is the position vector of the point, $\vec b$ is the slope and $n$ is any value in $R$ - {0}

Makes sense?

Comment: But again $n(B)$ isn't a vector?

Comment: Yep, it is. Made the edit.

Comment: But my question still remain uncleared that how do you change a single number lets say $b$ real number (partial derivative) into a vector?

Comment: When you do partial differentiation with respect to the three variables i.e x,y,z consider each one of those individually as the mutually perpendicular components of the slope vector. This vector is just an analog of slope in dimensions higher than 2.